# Prove that the intersection of two $\sigma$-algebra is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

My proof goes:

Let {$A_1 , A_2 $} be a family of two $\sigma$ -algebras and let $A \in A_1 \cap A_2$ Which means $A \in A_1$ and $A \in A_2$ and implies $A^c \in A_1$ and $A^c \in A_2 $ so $A^c \in A_1 \cap A_2$

Now let $A_j \in A_1 \cap A_2$ for $j\in J$ Then $A_j \in A_1 , A_j \in A_2$ $\forall j$ Therefore $\cup A_j \in A_1$ and $\cup A_j \in A_2$ Hence $\cup A_j \in A_1 \cap A_2$ and intersection of two $\sigma$-algebras is $\sigma$-algebra

Would this be correct? Is there another way of proving this?

Comment: It seems correct and most probably the only way to prove.

Comment: Notice that you can use the same argument to prove that the intersection of an arbitrary number of $\sigma$-algebras is still a $\sigma$-algebra

Comment: @gonzalo benavides: another way would be to use the identity $\sigma\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal A_i\right) = \bigcap_{i\in I}\sigma(\mathcal A_i)$

Comment: @lmaosome But that identity is actually a consequence of the countable version of what is asked here

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to mention that $|J| \leq |\mathbb N|$, otherwise this seems to be a correct proof.

Proving that something is a sigma-algebra is only really ever done by checking the definition, so you should always look for this kind of proof in such a case.